# Comparing data in PL/SQL with the input i want to compare

Tags: oracle, plsql

I like to create a PLSQL PROCEDURE to verify the data of the EMPLOYEE does not exist in DRIVER and MECHANIC.

I have create 1 records to test. However when i run EXEC Verify(2) with the records that is not i created for testing it will still show the tested records which is not i like to verify on.

I like to exec the PROCEDURE with the set of EMPLOYEE.E# that i select to run the compare of the EMPLOYEE do not exist in DRIVER and MECHANIC.

HERE is the PLSQL that i create.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Verify(enum IN EMPLOYEE.E#%TYPE) IS
eNo DRIVER.E#%TYPE;
eName EMPLOYEE.NAME%TYPE;

CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT DRIVER.E#, EMPLOYEE.NAME
    FROM DRIVER
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE
    ON EMPLOYEE.E# = DRIVER.E#
    WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MECHANIC WHERE DRIVER.E# = MECHANIC.E#);

BEGIN   
    OPEN c1;
    FETCH c1 into eNo, eName;
    IF c1%NOTFOUND THEN
        CLOSE c1;               
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Records Found');

    ELSE
        CLOSE c1;           
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('E#| NAME');
        FOR EmpRecord IN c1
        LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(EmpRecord.E# || ' | ' || EmpRecord.NAME || ' is in                   
              driver and mechanic.');
        END LOOP;
    END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. At first, you're not using your parameter inside the procedure, and second, your code does not reflect what you say in words, you need to read it again and change it to make your GrandMa understand what you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 
`CURSOR c1 IS` 
`SELECT  EMPLOYEE.E# , EMPLOYEE.NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EMPLOYEE.E#=enum
AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM MECHANIC a,DRIVER b WHERE a.E# = b.E# and a.E#=EMPLOYEE.#E);`


I have not yet tested this one, but I hope it helps.